# Push a ViewController from au CustomCell

Tags: iphone, pushviewcontroller, custom-cell

I've created a custom cell named "CustomPreviCell" (its the name of the NIb and the Identifier of the cell in this NIB). My customCell contains 6 labels and an imageView. The .m file corresponding to this cell is following :

```
@interface CustomPreviCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *iconImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *weatherLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailOneLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailTwoLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dayNumberLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dayTextLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *monthLabel;

@end
```

And implementation :

```
#import "CustomPreviCell.h"

@implementation CustomPreviCell
@synthesize iconImageView;
@synthesize weatherLabel;
@synthesize detailOneLabel;
@synthesize detailTwoLabel;
@synthesize dayNumberLabel;
@synthesize dayTextLabel;
@synthesize monthLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

}


@end
```

Now, i want display this cell in a tableView (of course!). So in my storyboard, i have created a new UITableView with one CustomCell prototype, and i refered the view to my class "SinglePreviViewController" which extends "UITableViewController". I implemented classic methods for tableView (numberOfRowsInSection: etc ...).

In the method "cellForRowAtIndexPath", i want to create, initialize and display my custom cells , so i writed :

```
NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCellPrevi";
CustomPreviCell *cell = (CustomPreviCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellPrevi" owner:self options:nil];

for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomPreviCell class]]){
        cell = (CustomPreviCell *)currentObject;

        NSString * iconName = [self loadIcon:indexPath.row];
        [cell.iconImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:iconName]];
        cell.detailOneLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@°C - %@mm",[descriptor.temperature objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], [descriptor.precipitations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.detailTwoLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ (%@) km/h - %@hPa",[descriptor.vent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[descriptor.rafales objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], [descriptor.pression objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.weatherLabel.text = [descriptor.temps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSDictionary * date = [self getDateComponentsFromXMLDate:[descriptor.date objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        if([[date valueForKey:@"dayNumber"] intValue] %2 == 0)
            [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.0]];
        else 
            [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.15]];


        cell.dayTextLabel.text = [date valueForKey:@"dayText"];
        cell.dayNumberLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[date valueForKey:@"dayNumber"],[date valueForKey:@"month"]];
        cell.monthLabel.text = [date valueForKey:@"hour"];

    }
}
return cell;
```

Let's launch my app : it works correctly ! My tableView contains my CustomPreviCells and display the content correctly. But... When i want to push a new viewController from these cells, its not working. I've connected my customCell (from the cell in my TableView in the storyboard) to the new viewcontroller (named DetailPreviViewcontroller), but it does nothing. My customCell is just selected.

Please help :)

**EDIT 1:**

```
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Hey !");
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"propertiesSegue"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Hello");
        SingleVillePropertiesViewController * destinationController = [segue destinationViewController];
        [destinationController setVille:ville];
    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailPreviSegue"])
    {
        DetailPreviViewController * destController = [segue destinationViewController];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:destController animated:YES];

        //TODO : set previDescriptor to my destController but it's not important 
        //       for this problem.
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**
Ok i don't have yet the solution to this problem, but i get rid of it by doing this :

1/ Create a new nib for the View controller you want to push (not in the storyboard)

2/ Set it the Class of your ViewController (in my case DetailPreviViewController) and the View of FilesOwner to the NIB View

3/ Push the view from the method "didSelectRowAtPath" with the navigationController.

I don't like this way to proceed, but it's for now, the only one which works...

Comment: Did you implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: No need to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` if he is using storyboard segues...

Comment: I don't need to implement didSelectRowAtPath. I didnt't in some other classes and it works perfectly. For this TableView i just want to set a descriptor to my DetailPreviViewController via "prepareForSegue", but when i click on a customCell, this method is not called.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have connected the **cell** in storyboard, and not the entire view controller. This can happen quite easily. One way to do this is to first **select** the cell and then do the dragging.

There is no need to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. That would render the whole storyboard segues useless...

Comment: When i select the link between my cell and the next View to push, my cell is blue highlighted => here is not the problem :/ But i agree with you : no need to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath...

Answer (score 0):

*Edited answer for segues:*

Try implementing this

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setValue1:@"something"];
        // Maybe you have to alloc init your view controller also

    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"B"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setValue1:@"something else"];
    }
}
```

Comment: As i said in the post above, i don't need to implement this function. But i tried to implement (just to try) and pushing my DetailPreviViewController from here. It pushes me an empty View ! (another mysteryous problem...)

Comment: Ok try creating the new viewController in the "prepareForSegue:" method

Comment: I never pass in this method when i select a cell. Here is the big problem. You can see the code of prepareForSegue: in the EDIT1 of my post.
When i Click on the properties button (in my Top Bar), it works and the first condition (identifier = propertiesSegue) is ok.
When i select a row, prepapreForSegue is not called...

Comment: Select your table view , cmd+click , go the arrow to your viewcontroller and select delegate

Comment: Yes delegate and Datasource are already linked to my viewcontroller... (if it wasn't the case, i could not load data in my cell, but i can )